# I'm trying to add a font to my react native app but im getting error of not closing a jsx tag but i closed all of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to add fonts to my app but along the way I ran into this error

> SyntaxError: C:\Users\arich\Documents\efees\App.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...? (69:5)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false
  };
}

    async componentDidMount() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
      }).then(() => {
        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
      });
    }

  render() {
    const finalValue = parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) +
    parseFloat(this.state.shippingCharge || 0)
    - parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) *
    parseFloat(this.state.paypalFeePercentage || 0)
    - parseFloat(this.state.paypalFee  || 0)
    - parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) *
    parseFloat(this.state.ebayFee || 0) - parseFloat(this.state.shippingCost || 0)
    - parseFloat(this.state.itemCost || 0);

    const inputStyle = this.state.inputStyleInactive;

    const ebaytTotal = this.state.ebayFee * this.state.soldPrice;

    const paypalTotal = this.state.paypalFeePercentage *
     this.state.soldPrice + this.state.paypalFee;

      EStyleSheet.build({ // always call EStyleSheet.build() even if you don't use global variables!

      });
   return (

     <View style={styles.container}>
```

I tried to add/remove opening and closing tags but i think the main cause of this error is this opening parenthesis but just not sure how to fix it also would appreciate an explanation for why this error was caused it would definitely help me for the future being that i'm a beginner always looking to learn lessons out of these moments when i'm just stumped

```
 {this.state.fontLoaded == true ? (
         <View style={styles.header}>
         <Text style={styles.headerText}>Efees</Text>
         </View>
```

this view is the one getting the error

```
    <View style={styles.blocks}>

     <View style={styles.inputs} >
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>1. Sold Price</Text>
     <NumberInput
     onchange={(soldPrice) => this.setState({ soldPrice })}
     />
     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>2. Shipping Charge</Text>

     <NumberInput
     onchange={(shippingCharge) => this.setState({ shippingCharge })}
     />
     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>3. Shipping Cost</Text>

     <NumberInput
     onchange={(shippingCost) => this.setState({ shippingCost })}
     />

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>4. Item Cost</Text>

     <NumberInput
     onchange={(itemCost) => this.setState({ itemCost })}
     />

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>5. Ebay Store?</Text>

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>6. Top Rated Seller?</Text>


     </View>
     </View>

     <View style={styles.results}>
      <Text style={styles.resultText}>eBay Fee:{ebaytTotal.toFixed(2)}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.resultText}>Paypal Fee:{paypalTotal.toFixed(2)}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.resultText}>Profit %{}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.profitResult}>TOTAL PROFIT:{finalValue.toFixed(2)}</Text>
      </View>
    ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
  }
      </View>

 );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because, you are returning multiple elements from your condition,

```
{this.state.fontLoaded == true ? ( ...
```

You need to wrap all your element with a wrapper element to create only 1 returning element.

For this you can use [`Fragments`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

**What is Fragments ?**

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Here also you have multiple ways to write `Fragment`.

```
import React from 'react'

{this.state.fontLoaded == true ? (
  <React.Fragment>
     <view></view>
     ...
     ...
  </React.Fragment>
 ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
}
```

**Or**

```
import React , { Fragment } from 'react'

{this.state.fontLoaded == true ? (
  <Fragment>
     <view></view>
     ...
     ...
  </Fragment>
 ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
}
```

**Or** even short syntax is `<> </>` (empty tags),

```
import React from 'react'

{this.state.fontLoaded == true ? (
  <>
     <view></view>
     ...
     ...
  </>
 ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
}
```